# Where to find/how to extract image hyperlinks from zipped docx document?

Tags: xml, hyperlink, zip, extract, docx

If you zip a docx file, open it with winrar and click on view you can see the zip folder structure of the document. In word/_rels/document.xml.rels you can find the text hyperlinks but unfortunately not the links the images show to. Is there a way to find/extract them?